# RESTful way to return different subsets of data

Tags: web-services, rest, restful-url, restful-architecture

I have a large data resource which I need to serve up in a RESTful manner. The resource is a large object containing lots of fields.

I have the requirement to filter this data into 2 view public and private information. One for internal systems and one for external for example.

What is the best RESTful approach to do this:

```
    localhost:9999/CAR?view=public
    localhost:9999/PrivateCar
    localhost:9999/PublicCar
```

Comment: Yes thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

```
localhost:9999/CAR?view=public
```

is the best idea. You can also use some kind of [resource query language](https://github.com/persvr/rql), but *views* are far much better here. Imagine just that one need to introduce new view. It's much easier to add new variable representing the view than new endpoint.